# Declare test dependency using Npm.depends

Tags: node.js, meteor

I would like to know how to declare a dependency on an Npm module in Meteor only in test.

While testing a package, I can easily declare a Npm dependency in `package.js` like this:

```
Npm.depends({
  ...
  'sinon': '1.15.3'
  ...
});
```

But I am only using `sinon` in test, and I want to make it explicit.

I tried the following with no success.

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  // # 1
  // can't do this because it is not a meteor module
  api.use('sinon');

  // # 2
  // can't because I have other production Npm dependencies
  // and Meteor only allows one `Npm.depends` call per `package.js`.
  // Also, not sure if nesting Npm.depends() is allowed at all.
  Npm.depends({
    'sinon': '1.15.3'
  });


});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about creating a meteor wrapper for sinon and then doing api.use() in onTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to wrap sinon into a package and `api.use` it. You can do the following:

```
$ meteor create --package sinon
```

Replace the contents of `packages/sinon` with the following:

**package.js**

```js
Package.describe({
  summary: 'Standalone test spies, stubs and mocks for JavaScript.'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0.4');
  api.export('sinon', 'server');
  api.addFiles('sinon.js');
  api.addFiles('post.js');
});
```

**post.js**

```js
sinon = this.sinon;
```

**sinon.js**

Download the latest version from [here](http://sinonjs.org/download/).

Finally in the package you are testing, you can add `api.use('sinon');` in your `Package.onTest`.

---

As an alternative to making your own package, you can just use one of the community versions available [here](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=sinon).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instruction. I understand that we are exporting `sinon` variable so that we can use it outside the package, but what is the meaning of `this.sinon` in `post.js`?

Comment: You'll often see weird-looking pre and post scripts which wrap 3rd-party code. It's a little complicated, but basically the only way to expose a symbol via a package is to declare a global variable (without `var`). The `global` object inside of a package is wrapped to prevent variables from leaking out - this is nice but results in some odd workarounds like the above.

Comment: Then, is `this` the package itself?

Comment: Yeah you can think of it that way - global to the package instead of global to the app.